# SonarLint Eclipse : Does it also analyze source code in "src/test"?

Tags: java, eclipse, sonarlint

In my company, we are currently using **SonarLint Eclipse** (version 3.1) in **connected mode** to SonarQube server (version 5.6), with SonarJava (version 4.7.1).

We have some plugins and some test plugins that we want to analyze from SonarLint Eclipse :

1.If the source code is in **"src/java"**, SonarLint works well and
   displays some issues detected according the rules defined from the
   SonarQube profile of our SonarQube server.

2.But if the source code is in **"src/test/"**, SonarLint does not display any issue in the view "SonarLint On The Fly". In this case, SonarLint logs show:

```
    ...src/test/..../MyClassTest.java
    1 files indexed
    Execute Sensor: JavaSquidSensor
    Configured Java source version (sonar.java.source): 8
    JavaClasspath initialization
    JavaClasspath initialization (done) | time=17ms
    JavaTestClasspath initialization
    JavaTestClasspath initialization (done) | time=15ms
    Java Main Files AST scan
    0 source files to be analyzed
    Java Main Files AST scan (done) | time=0ms
    Java Test Files AST scan
    1 source files to be analyzed
    0/0 source files have been analyzed
```

SonatLint seems to work differently between Java Main Files and Java Test Files.

Does there is a way to configure SonarLint in order that it works on the same way for Java Main Files and Java Test Files in connected mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SonarLint for Eclipse, you can configure which files are considered to be test sources.

Go to:

> Preferences -> SonarLint

And change the "Test file regular expressions".

Comment: Thanks. I changed the "Test file regular expressions" in the preferences of SonarLint and it works now. SonarLint analyzes on the same way Java Main Files and Java Test Files :-)

Comment: @lpa Can you help me understand what change you made to pick files in Test folders? My current expression is : **/*Test.*,**/test/**/* , its picking only src/main files and not src/test files.

Comment: @Sam, try to remove the complete expression in "Test file regular expressions".