# SonarLint - IntelliJ-Plugin - Analyze Test Classes

Tags: analysis, intellij-plugin, sonarlint

I’m using SonarLint-Plugin for Intellij, and I’m wondering why SonarLint is not analyzing the code of my test-classes when triggering the inspection by “Analyze with SonarLint” context-menu.

when i rename the folder from ‘test’ to e.g.‘abc’ the inspection works.

Is this a normal behaviour and is there a way to configure this?

Thanks in advance

Best Regards

Klaus

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43843455/sonarlint-eclipse-does-it-also-analyze-source-code-in-src-test ?

Comment: this is the sonarlint-plugin for eclipse, which offers - obviously - different settings. in intellij the "Test file regular expressions" is not available

Comment: It's a normal behavior to raise different issues in a source file vs a unit-test. See [Julien HENRY's answer](https://groups.google.com/g/sonarlint/c/JY6Moc_mUeQ/m/-eHD4Bx7BQAJ) regarding _"Most of our rules are intentionally not raising issues on test files, since we consider that this is not the same level of expectation"_.

Answer (score 1):

You can mark the directory as Test Sources. Then the Sonarlint will consider the all the files in the directory as test classes.

[image]